# Very different results using filter object and b,a coefficients

Tags: matlab, filtering, signal-processing, bandpass-filter

I'm comparing the output of digital filtering using MATLAB `filter` object and b-a coefficients using `tf` function, and they are really different. I'll appreciate if anyone could point me out in the right direction. Here there are my results and the test script (download [`data.txt`](https://yadi.sk/d/IbNeZ-0-kLfiQA)):

```
srate=64;
freqrange=[0.4 3.5];
file='data.txt';
load(file);
file=split(file,'.');
file=file{1};
data=eval(file);

st=srate*60;
ed=srate*60*2;
data=data(st:ed);%1 minute data
m=numel(data);

x=data;
R=0.1;%10% of signal
Nr=50;
NR=min(round(m*R),Nr);%At most 50 points
x1=2*x(1)-flipud(x(2:NR+1));%maintain continuity in level and slope
x2=2*x(end)-flipud(x(end-NR:end-1));
x=[x1;x;x2];

[xx,dbp]=bandpass(x,freqrange,srate);%same result if use filter(dbp,xx)
data_fil=xx(NR+1:end-NR);

[b,a]=dbp.tf;
xx=filter(b,a,x);
data_fil_ba=xx(NR+1:end-NR);

f=figure;
s(1)=subplot(2,1,1,'Parent',f);
plot(s(1),[data data_fil])
title(s(1),'dbp')
s(2)=subplot(2,1,2,'Parent',f);
plot(s(2),[data data_fil_ba])
title(s(2),'ba')
linkaxes(s,'x');
```

and here there is the result I obtain:

[image: filters outputs]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is caused by numerical instability in the `[b,a]` filter representation, from the Matlab [docs](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/butter.html#bucsflt):

> **Numerical Instability of Transfer Function Syntax**
>
> In general, use the `[z,p,k]` syntax to design IIR filters. To analyze or implement your filter, you can then use the `[z,p,k]` output with `zp2sos`. If you design the filter using the `[b,a]` syntax, you might encounter numerical problems. These problems are due to round-off errors and can occur for n as low as 4.

Looking at your filter with `fvtool`, you will see that the first plot (of the `digitalFilter` object) is smooth, where as the second plot, generated with the transfer function representation is very unstable in the lower frequency range. The magnitude of this filter even gets above 0 dB, meaning that the filter is unstable and will amplify these frequencies. That is why your results blows up, it goes to ~10^92.

The solution is to simply not use the transfer function (`[b,a]`) representation, and instead use the `digitalFilter`, or `[z,p,k]` representation. See [here](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/control/examples/switching-model-representation.html#GSModelTypeConversions-3) for more info on why to be careful on switching filter/model representations.

[image]

Code

```
srate=64;
freqrange=[0.4 3.5];
[~,dbp]=bandpass(rand(100,1),freqrange,srate);
[b,a]=dbp.tf;
fvtool(dbp)
fvtool(b,a)
```

Comment: thanks for your response, it was what i was afraid but i needed confirmation. The thing is that i need to implement a filter in C, so that's why i tried with b-a coefficients. I'm asking another question about zero-pole-gain implementation.